# Python - Display key values before and after Findall(regex, output)

Tags: python, findall

I am trying to extract MAC addresses for each NIC from Dell's RACADM output such that my output should be like below:

```
NIC.Slot.2-2-1  -->  24:84:09:3E:2E:1B
```

I have used the following to extract the output

```
output =  subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p {} ssh {}@{} racadm {}".format(args.password,args.username,args.hostname,args.command),shell=True).decode()
```

Part of output

https://pastebin.com/cz6LbcxU

Each component details are displayed between ------ lines

I want to search Device Type = NIC and then print Instance ID and Permanent MAC.

```
regex = r'Device Type = NIC'
match = re.findall(regex, output, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
match = re.finditer(regex, output, flags=re.S)
```

I used both the above functions to extract the match but how do I print `[InstanceID: NIC.Slot.2-2-1]` and `PermanentMACAddress` of the Matched regex.

Please help anyone?

Comment: Objective: Search all NICs in the output (str) and map with corresponding MACs. Sample output https://pastebin.com/Bi7cCsuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly,
you can search for the pattern `[InstanceID: ...]` to get the instance id,
and `PermanentMACAddress = ...` to get the MAC address.

Here's one way to do it:

```
import re

match_inst = re.search(r'\[InstanceID: (?P<inst>[^]]*)', output)
match_mac = re.search(r'PermanentMACAddress = (?P<mac>.*)', output)

inst = match_inst.groupdict()['inst']
mac = match_mac.groupdict()['mac']

print('{}  -->  {}'.format(inst, mac))
# prints: NIC.Slot.2-2-1  -->  24:84:09:3E:2E:1B
```

If you have multiple records like this and want to map NIC to MAC, you can get a list of each, zip them together to create a dictionary:

```
inst = re.findall(r'\[InstanceID: (?P<inst>[^]]*)', output)
mac = re.findall(r'PermanentMACAddress = (?P<mac>.*)', output)

mapping = dict(zip(inst, mac))
```

Comment: Thanks but this will only extract the NIC and MAC but not map them.

Comment: @BuggyB I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. But I took a guess and updated my answer. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Hi, Thanks but this will not solve the problem fully as the output file will not always have nic, mac pairs in a section. Sorry should have been more explicit:

Actual Data: https://pastebin.com/czX2EZnN
Code Written: https://pastebin.com/WAysx9aT

Comment: Maybe I need to play with string.split(pattern, 1)[0]

Comment: @BuggyB that's really a crucial piece of info, completely missing from your original post. It's extremely frustrating to answer one question that morphs into a different question. I think you should ask a new question, but first maybe pause and think, and make sure to not forget critical details.

Comment: @BuggyB as for the solution, it seems the data has sections, identified by `-----` delimiter lines. You could split on that to obtain sub-sections, and then you could process the sub-sections one by one, using the first technique in my answer. If a section doesn't have both nic and mac, you can ignore and move on to the next.

Comment: Apologies ... noob with python and first time on this website. I used configparse.ConfigParser() as suggested by other guy but it says "no section headers error". Which method should I use to split and regex for "---". Thanks

Comment: @BuggyB you could split to sections using `parts = re.split(r"-{20,}", output)`. But as I said, solving this part of the problem belongs to a new question.

Comment: Hi Janos ... thanks for your advice ... I got what I wanted https://pastebin.com/muvfwE4d

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks like INI file content, you could try to parse them using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html).

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read_string(output)
>>> for section in config.sections():
...     print(section)
...     print(config[section]['Device Type'])
... 
InstanceID: NIC.Slot.2-2-1
NIC
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, Maurice but I get no section headers error ... right as the output string does not have header https://pastebin.com/Bi7cCsuv